# Adding and Removing Event Listeners that Point to Function Declarations inside Constructor Function Expression

Tags: javascript

I have a problem figuring out how to organize these sets of expressions in a way that works. My constructor is a component of a game editor. Inside of this constructor I have a method that handles when the player clicks on an SVG on the document calling the moveObject expression. The move object correctly moves the object and it seems like inner onMouseMove function declaration is working as intended, but I cannot figure out how to remove these listeners.

I tried bind(this) on the removes too, but those didn't work. Before I try to mess with the function expressions and declarations I wanted to see if any of you had any thoughts on how I could write this code more efficiently. I feel like it is a little clunky right now.

```
function Editor(game){
    this.active = null;

    this.moveObject = function(event) {
        var x = event.clientX; 
        var y = event.clientY;
        let element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        if (element.classList.contains('editorMoveable')) {
            do {
                element = element.parentElement; 
                if (element.classList.contains('gameObject'))
                    break;
            } while(element.tagName != "body");
        }

        this.activeElement = element;
        var key = splitElementID(this.activeElement.id);
        this.active = this.game.objects[key.object][key.subObject];

        let shiftX = event.clientX - this.activeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        let shiftY = event.clientY - this.activeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var globalTransform = this.game.calculateGlobals(this.active);

        var newPos = moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        this.active.Transform.position.x = newPos.newPosX;
        this.active.Transform.position.y = newPos.newPosY;
        this.activeElement.style.transform = 'translate(' + newPos.newPosX + 'rem, ' + newPos.newPosY + 'rem)';

        function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
            var newPosX = ((pageX - shiftX)/remSize - globalTransform.position.x);
            var newPosY = ((pageY - shiftY)/remSize - globalTransform.position.y);
            var newRotX = (0);
            var newRotY = (0);
            var newSclX = (1);
            var newSclY = (1);
            return {"newPosX": newPosX, "newPosY": newPosY}
        }

        function onMouseMove(event) {
            var newPos = moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
            this.active.Transform.position.x = newPos.newPosX;
            this.active.Transform.position.y = newPos.newPosY;
            this.activeElement.style.transform = 'translate(' + newPos.newPosX + 'rem, ' + newPos.newPosY + 'rem)';
        }

        function onMouseUp() {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
            this.activeElement = null;
            this.active = null;
        }

        // Move the elem on mousemove
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove.bind(this));
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp.bind(this));
    };
};
```

Results are as explained in the upper problem. Since the event is not being removed (they stack on each click) I get "cannot read property of null".

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: `cannot read property of null` This sounds like a different issue - what exactly is the error message, and on which line does it occur?

Comment: Since MouseUp gets run I get that error due to the activeElement being null. Basically the Event Listener is still running when it shouldn't be. Barmars suggestion fixed my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `onMouseMove` is not the same function as `onMouseMove.bind(this)`.

What you can do is assign that to a variable, and then use that variable in both the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` calls.

```
    let thisOnMouseMove = onMouseMove.bind(this);
    let thisOnMouseUp = onMouseUp.bind(this);

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        var newPos = moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        this.active.Transform.position.x = newPos.newPosX;
        this.active.Transform.position.y = newPos.newPosY;
        this.activeElement.style.transform = 'translate(' + newPos.newPosX + 'rem, ' + newPos.newPosY + 'rem)';
    }

    function onMouseUp() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', thisOnMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', thisOnMouseUp);
        this.activeElement = null;
        this.active = null;
    }

    // Move the elem on mousemove
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', thisOnMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', thisOnMouseUp);
```

Comment: Solved my problem and will definitely use this approach for a few other areas that feel poorly written to me. Thank you!!!